# Can't return value from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

JSON file:

```
{
    "stock": [
            {
                "symbol": "AVGO",
                "name": "Broadcom Ltd.",
                "sector": "Technology",
                "industry": "Semiconductors",
                "SCTR": "97.8",
                "delta": "2.5",
                "close": "154.97",
                "vol": "2297509"
            }, 
            {
                "symbol": "CBS",
                "name": "CBS Corp.",
                "sector": "Cyclicals",
                "industry": "Entertainment",
                "SCTR": "92.3",        
                "delta": "-3.6",
                "close": "53.58",
                "vol": "4045416"
            }
       ]
}
```

PHP:

```
$jsona = json_decode($json, true);
echo $jsona['stock']['symbol'];
```

Why I can't get the symbol?
And how can I get all symbol value?
Thanks!

Comment: Do `print_r($jsona);` then you see the structure and that you got multiple symbol values.

Comment: Original JSON is here but I can't get my value too      http://stockcharts.com/j-sum/sum?cmd=sctr&view=L&timeframe=W

Comment: @FelixKling It is valid json. You probably just had a copy error while putting it into jsonlint.

Comment: @Rizier123: I guess the formatting in the question threw me off.

Comment: sorry for my poor formatting as the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of "stock" is an array.  So you can either do:

```
echo $jsona['stock'][0]['symbol'];
echo $jsona['stock'][1]['symbol'];
```

or loop through them:

```
foreach ($jsona['stock'] as $stock) {
    echo "Symbol: {$stock['symbol']}\n";
    echo "Name: {$stock['name']}\n";
    echo "Sector: {$stock['sector']}\n\n";
}
```

which produces:

```
Symbol: AVGO
Name: Broadcom Ltd.
Sector: Technology

Symbol: CBS
Name: CBS Corp.
Sector: Cyclicals
```

Comment: It's work, great!  But I still cannot get the idea if the JSON changed to<br>    [
            {
                "symbol": "AVGO",
                "name": "Broadcom Ltd."
            }, 
            {
                "symbol": "CBS",
                "name": "CBS Corp."
            }
       ]

Comment: @Fireghost: Read the duplicate question. It teaches you what these structures really mean and how to access them in a general way, not just specific to your data. That will hopefully allow you to apply that knowledge to differently structured data.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$jsona['stock'][0]['symbol']` because stock contains an array so you have to specify which element of the array you're accessing. You can then use a foreach loop to loop through each element of the `$jsona['stock']` array.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `$stocks['stock']` is the array you want to loop through. I changed the variable names to make some sense of the loop:

```
$stocks = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($stocks['stock'] AS $stock){
    echo $stock['symbol'] ."<br>";
}
```

Returns

> AVGO
>
> CBS